# Erro método main

Tags: java, stack

Alguem pode me dizer uq esta dando errado ? diz que esta faltando o metodo main, mais nao era pra acontecer isso

```
public class PilhaEstatica {
        
            String vet[];
            int topo;
            
            PilhaEstatica(int tamanho) {    // Criar uma pilha vazia
                vet = new String[tamanho];  // Cria a pilha com um tamanho
                topo = 0;                   // Topo 0 significa pilha vazia
            }
            
        boolean vazia() {               // Verifica se a pilha está vazia 
            return topo == 0;           // Se topo for 0, pilha está vazia
        }
        
        boolean cheia() {               // Verifica se a pilha está cheia
            return vet.length == topo;  // Se o topo é igual ao tamanho da pilha
        }
       
        boolean inserir(String valor) { // Inserir um novo elemento na pilha
            if (cheia()) {              // Se a pilha está cheia retorna falso
                return false;
            }
            vet[topo] = valor;          // Coloca a informação no topo
            topo++;                     // O topo agora é mais em cima da pilha
            return true;                // Se conseguiu excluir, retorna verdadeiro
        }
       
        String retirar() {              // Retira o elemento do topo da pilha
            if (vazia()) {              // Se a pilha está vazia, retorna nulo
                return null;                    
            }
            topo--;                     // Agora o topo vai descer pra tirar o elemento do topo
            return vet[topo];           // Retorna o elemento que estava no topo
        }
       }
```

Comment: "isso" o quê ? Qual o problema ? Qual o erro ?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -5):

Para rodar um código Java, você precisa criar uma classe com um método main. O método main é o ponto de entrada do programa e é nele que o código é executado.

No seu código, você criou uma classe chamada PilhaEstatica, mas não criou um método main. Você precisa adicionar um método main à sua classe para poder rodar o programa.

Aqui está como o código poderia ficar com o método main adicionado:

```
public class PilhaEstatica {

    String vet[];
    int topo;

    PilhaEstatica(int tamanho) {    // Criar uma pilha vazia
        vet = new String[tamanho];  // Cria a pilha com um tamanho
        topo = 0;                   // Topo 0 significa pilha vazia
    }

    boolean vazia() {               // Verifica se a pilha está vazia 
        return topo == 0;           // Se topo for 0, pilha está vazia
    }

    boolean cheia() {               // Verifica se a pilha está cheia
        return vet.length == topo;  // Se o topo é igual ao tamanho da pilha
    }

    boolean inserir(String valor) { // Inserir um novo elemento na pilha
        if (cheia()) {              // Se a pilha está cheia retorna falso
            return false;
        }
        vet[topo] = valor;          // Coloca a informação no topo
        topo++;                     // O topo agora é mais em cima da pilha
        return true;                // Se conseguiu excluir, retorna verdadeiro
    }

    String retirar() {              // Retira o elemento do topo da pilha
        if (vazia()) {              // Se a pilha está vazia, retorna nulo
            return null;                    
        }
        topo--;                     // Agora o topo vai descer pra tirar o elemento do topo
        return vet[topo];           // Retorna o elemento que estava no topo
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Aqui você pode colocar o código que quer rodar quando o programa for executado
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado! Se você ainda tiver dúvidas ou precisar de mais informações, basta me perguntar